# why its written md5 along with download of any language such as php,ruby etc?

Tags: php, python, ruby, md5

This question may sound silly but while navigating any computer language site i usually encounter a MD5 value written within bracket or beside the download link of the language.

**why MD5 is been provided ?
What is its use there ? Does it help in downloading process ? which value's MD5 is given over there ? Is it there release version's MD5 value.**

Such as:

1. [PHP](http://php.net/downloads.php) //MD5 is privided
2. [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) //MD5 is given
3. [Python](http://www.python.org/download/) //again MD5

Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some of the downloading mirrors will be hacked to inject code in binaries, md5 of binaries will be changed. So by checking md5 of downloaded file you can be sure that your file is not modified.

Comment: thanks fr sharing.. :)

but why dont we use sha1 or any other type of encryption ?

Comment: @Rahul md5 is not *strictly* speaking *encryption*. This is a *message-digest* ("hash") algorithm. It is not reversible. Think of this as a *finger print* for the file. Other algorithms are available. But for that purpose md5 is sufficient (even if it has been proved since something like 10 years that one could forge a fake document having the same md5 hash as the original).

Comment: @Rahul I will post a slightly edited version of that comment as answer, since I didn't read with careful attention the present answer.

Answer (score 1):

md5 is not *strictly* speaking *encryption*. This is a *message-digest* ("hash") algorithm. It is not reversible. Think of this as a *finger print* for the file. Other algorithms are available: SHA-1, SHA-256 to name few popular options.

Obviously, all hash algorithms are vulnerable to collision (there is a *finite* number of hash values, but an *infinite* number of input documents). The chances of collision "by mistake" are small, but it has been proved since something like 10 years ago that one could forge a fake document having the same md5 hash as the original. In fact, for md5, this is even worst, because I'm able to *choose* the prefix of the "fake" document, and by adding some "magic garbage" at the end of it, to produce a "fake" archive with the same md5 hash as the original.

As of today, the main use of md5 *should be* to check the integrity of a document against download errors. Not much more than that.

**It *shouldn't be* used to protect against *malicious* tempering.**

Comment: but as we know MD5 needs some value to be passed in it. Which value is been used ? Is it version number or any random value to generate that hash ?

Comment: @Rahul when you download a file, the md5 given is usually the md5 hash of the whole archive. This is how you check the *archive*'s integrity.